# Include default responses to swagger documentation

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I am building an application using swagger in python. I specified all outcomes produces by my code in the swagger `yaml` file. Connexion, the library which I am using, also checks for validity of the data provided by the client and might for example return

```
{
  "detail": "Invalid Content-type (application/json), expected JSON data",
  "status": 415,
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "type": "about:blank"
}
```

For the documentation to be complete the ui should consists of all the response messages specified by me and the implicit response messages of connexion.

Is there a way to add all this implicit responses to the swagger-ui?

Comment: I just add them in to the API specification directly.

Comment: I mean yes, but then you need to be aware of all the changes which the maintainers might do to the behaviour of the library.